# Show only HTML elements that fit fully in the parent div

Tags: javascript, html, css, ecmascript-6, sass

**[JS Fiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/7c0djzn7/)**

[image: Partial fit elements visible]

I have a div which contains user generated HTML elements. Each line in the div can be any number of characters, but displays only on one line, and does not wrap. **My issue is that partial elements are shown vertically**, and due to the variety of HTML elements, I cannot anticipate exactly how many lines of text can fit.

The image below shows the issue, in this case using only list item elements (highlighted with a red arrow.) I've included the HTML and CSS are below as well.

I have been looking for a ReactJS compatible solution to prevent element that do not fit completely from being displayed (I'm open to nearly anything CSS, NPM module, JavaScript snippets, just no jQuery.) All elements needs to remain at a static size, so dynamically resizing the text or container is also not suitable unfortunately.

The solution need only work in Chrome.

Unfortunately despite searching for solutions in the form of modules on NPM or CSS solutions such as `-webkit-line-clamp`, I've found nothing suitable. `-webkit-line-clamp` will only work (as far as I can tell) on text within a single element, so it will fix a paragraph with 5 lines, but it will not fix 5 single line paragraphs.

How can I solve this?

Comment: HTML in the provided jsFiddle snippet is invalid. The permitted content of [`span` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/span) is [Phrasing content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_categories#Phrasing_content) only.

Comment: since your height is fixed, use wrapper element to add padding and set fixed height in `em`'s to set number of visible lines. Fix line-height issues.